# Static Event Handlers in C#

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a Silverlight application. I want to track whether someone is online or offline in my application. Because of this, I thought I would determine that in the App.xaml.cs file. In an attempt to accomplish this, I added the following code:

```
internal static bool IsOnline = false;

public static event EventHandler NetworkAddress_Changed;
private static void NetworkChange_NetworkAddressChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  IsOnline = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
  if (NetworkAddress_Changed != null)
    NetworkAddress_Changed(null, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

My hope was that a page in my application could bind to this event handler and respond accordingly and check App.IsOnline. However, I don't know how to wire it up properly. In my startup event handler of App.xaml.cs, I have the following code:

```
NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged += new NetworkAddressChangedEventHandler(NetworkChange_NetworkAddressChanged);
```

Unfortunatley, the `NetworkChange_NetworkAddressChanged` event handler never gets called. Is what I'm trying to do possible? If so, how?

Comment: How did you test? Did you remove the cable, shutdown the wireless?

Comment: Generally be careful with static events. Events hold a strong reference to the object, so any subscribers to the event should use `-=` when the object is not longer used to allow it to get GCed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declaring an event isn't enough, there has to be code that actually raises the event.  Looks like you tried something and ended up having one event raising another.  Not good enough.

That code is otherwise hard to come by, the NetworkInterface class doesn't have any events itself.  You'll need to use a timer and periodically call GetIsNetworkAvailable().  Now you can fire an event when its return value changes.

Comment: Let me rephrase a bit. I'm trying to bind to the NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.networkaddresschanged(v=VS.95).aspx) in my App.xaml.cs. When this event fires, I want to do some work and then fire off an event that my code can subscribe to. Is this possible?

Comment: That event is raised when the *IP address* changes.  That would be quite rare, you'd have to (say) force the DHCP lease to be renewed.  What do you *really* want to observe?